# Errors when installing Token

Tags: tokens, installation

I installed the Token module, and it produced a bunch of errors. I accidentally navigated away from the page displaying the errors, and now I'm left wondering what future problems these errors might cause.

Is there any way to find out what went wrong with the install?

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: did you use stable version of the module?

Answer (score 1):

admin/reports/dblog will show you the last messages logged by Drupal. To see the menu, you need to enable the "Database logging" module, which is a core module present also in Drupal 6.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm not seeing dblog anywhere under reports. I am seeing recent log reports but can't seem to find anything about the errors in there.

Comment: PS I'm using durpal 7.0

Comment: You will need to enable the core module, think it is called database logging in d7

Answer (score 0):

I have often seen errors generated when installing new modules that disappear of their own accord.  It is quite possible that the newly enabled module is not finding or providing information it needs until the database is updated fully, or caches are cleared etc.  Token is a very commonly used, stable module.  If you have a problem you will continue to have error messages.  Your best protection against any future problems is to establish a regular back-up routine for both your site code and database.  If you have Drush and Git working on your development site, they make this process very simple, although if you are not familiar with them, there is a set-up and learning curve. If your in this for the long hauls, then it will be worth your while to set them up.